# Avro schema returned as bytes when using azure event hub source connector

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

We are now using the confluent 6.1.0 and try to connect to Azure even Hub. We can see the data coming but when come to schema, it always shows bytes. Can anyone give us some idea about how to solve it?

```
{

"name": "eventhub_to_kafka_pullt12",

"config": {

"confluent. topic. bootstrap. servers": "broker:29092",

"connector .class": "io.confluent.connect.azure.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceConnector",

" kafka . topic": "evenhubt5",

"tasks. max": "1",

"max. events": "10",

"azure. eventhubs .sas .keyname": "xxx",
 
"azure.eventhubs.sas.key": "xxx",

"azure.eventhubs.namespace": "xxx",

"azure.eventhubs.hub.name": "xxx",

"offsets.topic.replication.factor": "1",

"confluent.license.topic.replication.factor":"1",

"transaction.state.log.replication.factor": "1",

"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",

"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://xxxx:8081",

"value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",

"transaction.state.log.replication.factor": "1"

}

 }
```

We are using azure-eventhub-connector:1.2.1 and the error:

[image: byte in value schema]

Answer (score 0):

Since EventHubs is Kafka-like, there is no information within the record keys or values that can be decoded to form a schema (compared to a database table, for example). Therefore, you need to use `ByteArrayConverter` or `StringConverter` to consume into another Kafka cluster as-is. Using the AvroConverter will *force* byte/string Connect schemas into that Avro type.

If the original producer used the Schema Registry when producing the data into EventHubs, then downstream (after using Connect) consumers (such as Control Center) can still use AvroDeserializer with the same Schema Registry address as the bytes would be unchanged (the original schema would remain intact, and not "wrapped" within a bytes schema structure).